# CakePHP Skel and MIT License

Tags: cakephp, licensing

I've used Cake bake to start off a project.
I notice that it has the MIT license in the generated files.

How do I deal with that? Am I not allowed to used this skel in closed source projects?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using an old CakePHP version because the license information in the bake templates have been removed since v2.4.0: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/051fc0c14094be5c1ec8bc03a791087a13168f4c So, by updating your CakePHP version you no longer have to worry about this question.

Comment: Oh great! Googling didn't show any of that up for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

From http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

So you can use it, modify it, etc, as long as the copyright notice is not deleted.

Comment: And the permission notice as well! I don't want to give everyone permission to copy my app!'